# python vlc bindings for windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, wxpython

I am on Windows, and I wish to use Python Bindings for VLC. I've already downloaded the module from https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc as per the instruction. But, still I can't import the module.

The error looks like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  import vlc
  File "c:\python27\python-vlc-1.1.2\vlc.py", line 173, in <module>
  dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "c:\python27\python-vlc-1.1.2\vlc.py", line 150, in find_lib
  dll = ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

My aim is to stream the openCV webcam video inside a wxPython window using vlc instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I was trying to load a 32-bit dll from a 64-bit process, that's why it doesn't worked out. Finally I am able to fix it by using a 64-bit dll.

Comment: I confirm, install VLC 64 bit to solve the problem. Put vlc.py in VLC installation directory and import vlc

Comment: Works for me too! Thank you!